# referencing dynamically created controls in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created a Razor Class Library, with my own controls.  I am now using this library in my Blazor server app.  I dynamically add the controls on the HTML code, in a for loop.  But, once the controls are added, how do I reference the controls in my applications code?  I don't think I can add a reference to each control, as the number of controls being added can change.  Here is an example of my code:

```
<div class="col-12">
    @foreach (MyModel new_control_model in p.list_of_control_models){
       <myCustomControl model = "new_control_model"></myCustomControl >
   }
</div>
```

Once the controls are added to my page, I want to be able to reference the controls.  But how?  Is there a way to add the controls to a list, while they are being added to the webpage?  Or some other way to reference them?  For example:

```
@code{
   private void GetValues(){
       //iterate over all myCustomControl  on the page and call a method from the control
   }
}
```

Thanks
jason

Comment: What are you trying to do once you have them by reference? I'd say there is an easier way than maintaining a list of references to this component. Let me know so I can get back to you on what you are asking or an easier alternative.

Comment: Hello.  I am dynamically adding a list (about 30 or so) of Razor controls to my page.  Because as the developer, I could be adding more controls as users request it, I need to be able to easily add new controls.  Having to create 30+ variables that the control can reference seems like a bad idea.  Do you have a better option?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how this works.  I assume it is getting added by reference.  But, if I do this:

```
<div class="col-12">
    @foreach (MyModel new_control_model in p.list_of_control_models){
       //include adding a reference to a dictionary
       <myCustomControl @ref="myComponents[new_control_model.id]" model = "new_control_model"></myCustomControl >
   }
</div>

@code{
   //by reference I assume, the control gets added to this dictionary
   private Dictionary<string, myCustomControl > myComponents = new Dictionary<string, myCustomControl >();

  private void ButtonPress()
    {
        foreach (var item in myComponents)
        {
            string id = item.Key;
            object myObject = item.Value;
            string output = "";
            if (myObject.GetType().FullName == "MyComponentLibrary.myCustomControl ")
            {
                myCustomControl myControl = (myCustomControl )myObject;
                output = myControl.GetControlValue();
            }            
        }
    }    
  }
```

Comment: Why was this marked down?  Is there a better solution?